# WCF Multiple Base Classes in one interface?

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

i just wanted to know if it is possible to use more than one base class in one interface. I face the problem that i am using 2 (and there will be more) base classes for one interface. Using the first one is no problem at all, but when i try to work with the second one, it does not work.

I write down the code in short

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://bla.ServiceModel.Samples", SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ObservableCollection<Models.Model1>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ObservableCollection<Models.MOdel2>))]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    ObservableCollection<Models.Model1> AccessModel1();

    [OperationContract]
    ObservableCollection<Models.Model2> AccessModel2(string group);
}
```

After connecting with a client, creating a collection of Model1 works fine. When i try to create a collection of Model2, it simply crashes. The inner exception is "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Model1 and 2 contain different information, but have the same structure.

Is there a fundamentally mistake or something else?

If you need any further information, you are welcome!

*Update*

I will post the model classes. Maybe i am just blind and cant see the error.

```
[DataContract]
public class Model2
{
    private string status;
    private string name;
    private string telephone;

    public Model2(string sStatus, string sName, string sTelephone)
    {
        Status = sStatus;
        Name = sName;
        Telephone = sTelephone;
    }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 0)]
    public string Status
    {
        get { return status; }
        set { status = value; }
    }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 2)]
    public string Telephone
    {
        get { return telephone; }
        set { telephone = value; }
    }
}

internal class Model2Builder: ObservableCollection<Model2>
{
    public Model2Builder(string group)
        : base()
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new Database().GetModel2Data(group);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                Add(new Model2(row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString(), row[2].ToString()));
            }

            dt.Dispose();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Code for log...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and it worked - it could be to do with the contents of your model classes - try adding a trace listener to your service web.config to get better error info: <system.diagnostics><sources><source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning" propagateActivity="true"><listeners><add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\service-log.svclog"/></listeners></source></sources></system.diagnostics>

Comment: Hm, i have enabled a tracer, but there doesnt seem to be new info on what exactly it crashes. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I think you just opened a big can of worms.  OO and SOA.  Here's a post of interest: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/6b70e9f4-52bc-4fa9-a0ff-c0859e041e85/

Comment: your post was useful. after reading the thread, i have added (again ^^") ServiceKnownType for the Model2Builder class in my interface and it responded with an error that there was no standard contructor class. added it and now it works. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your model classes have you tried adding parameterless constructors - I'm pretty sure the data contract serializer requires requires parameterless constructors, i.e.

```
[DataContract]
public class Model2
{
    private string status;
    private string name;
    private string telephone;

    public Model2(){}

    public Model2(string sStatus, string sName, string sTelephone)
    {
        Status = sStatus;
        Name = sName;
        Telephone = sTelephone;
    }
    ...etc
```

Comment: you were right, but not for Model2, what has been missing was the standard constructor for the Model2Builder class. I have added it and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying to do here. Do your models implements a base class ?

ServiceKnownTypeAttribute is intended to declare a hierarchy of types that can be present in an object graph and that are not already present in the service interface.

As you already expose Models1 and Models2 in you interface, you don't need to specify them with ServiceKnownTypeAttribute.

For example:

```
[DataContract]
public class Shape { }

[DataContract]
public class Rectangle : Shape { }

[DataContract]
public class Square : Shape { }

[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Rectangle))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Square))]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Shape[] GetShapes();
}

public class Service : IService
{
    [OperationBehavior]
    public Shape[] GetShapes()
    {
        return new Shape[] {
            new Square(),
            new Rectangle()
        };
    }
}
```

Note that you could also use the [KnownTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx):

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Rectangle))]
[KnownType(typeof(Shape))]
public class Shape { }

[DataContract]
public class Rectangle : Shape { }

[DataContract]
public class Square : Shape { }
```

Comment: yes, you are right. i had added the ServiceKnownTypeAttribute when i worked with objects, changed it back later to the collections. i will update my initial post with the models. Maybe i have forgotten something.